# Ruby error handling with external request

Tags: ruby, json, api

I am making an external request and using HTTPARTY for the JSON file and then am parsing it.
BUT should the request fail (the file no longer exists or is a bad uri) how can I handle errors so I could still display the page?
Not sure of how best to protect the application from this point of failure and I have not done much in error handling.

```
def api_fetch(url)
  JSON.parse HTTParty.get(url).response.body
end

api_fetch('http://example.com/data.json')['test']
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work. It will check if the method returns nil when you call it.

```
def api_fetch(url)
    begin
      JSON.parse HTTParty.get(url).response.body
    rescue
      nil
    end
  end
```

Comment: will add something in to check if method returns nil when called. thanks

Comment: I'd suggest you also log the exception that's raised.  Will prevent a lot of frustration later.